# How to identify which disk failed on RAID 10?

Tags: nfs, raid, kernel-panic

RAID 10 set up from 16 SATA (4TB) disks. How to identify from pictures which disk is failed?

Here is my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `dd` from the good drive, and don't pull the drive with a flashing indicator

Comment: How to find which disk is sda2-8?

Comment: @GaniRakhmatov It's impossible to answer your question with the (lack of) information provided. In the case of a single disk failure, you shouldn't be seeing any of these errors in the first place. You have to check RAID metadata, and SMART data. Also this system probably needs better documentation, labels, ...

Comment: JDB2 `sda2-8` is not RAID related. You get that with any ext4 filesystem (if you create a loop device with ext4 and write to it you will see a `jbd2/loop0-8` process. That's just an implementation detail of the filesystem.

Comment: @frostschutz I've checked SMART and there is no errors

Answer (score 0):

If it is a software raid, take a look at the status

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid10] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4]
md0 : active raid10 sdb2[1] sdd2[3] sdc2[2] sda2[0]
      419168112 blocks super 1.2 4K chunks 2 near-copies [4/4] [UUUU]
unused devices: <none>
```

Get the drive status and serial numbers:

```
# parallel -v smartctl -a ::: /dev/sd[abcd] | egrep '/dev/|Model:|Number:|^No Errors Logged'
smartctl -a /dev/sda
Device Model:     ST500DM002-1BD142
Serial Number:    Z6EDYYSG
No Errors Logged
smartctl -a /dev/sdb
Device Model:     ST500DM002-1BD142
Serial Number:    Z6EDYPX4
No Errors Logged
smartctl -a /dev/sdc
Device Model:     ST500DM002-1BD142
Serial Number:    Z6EDYY7V
No Errors Logged
smartctl -a /dev/sdd
Device Model:     ST500DM002-1BD142
Serial Number:    Z6EE03BR
No Errors Logged
```

Show the kernel scsi boot messages:

```
#journalctl -b-0 -tkernel | grep +A5 'scsi .* Direct-Access'

Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST500DM002-1BD14 HP74 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel:  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
--
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST500DM002-1BD14 HP74 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel:  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3
--
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST500DM002-1BD14 HP74 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel:  sdc: sdc1 sdc2 sdc3
--
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST500DM002-1BD14 HP74 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Mar 18 05:59:16 host-1 kernel:  sdd: sdd1 sdd2 sdd3
```

... or without journal

```
grep +A5 'scsi .* Direct-Access' /var/log/{dmesg,kernel,boot}*
```

Comment: It is a hardware RAID.